# ¿Cómo elimino las stopwords de mi texto?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

No consigo eliminar las *"stopwords"*. ¿Es necesario que convierta `texto_m_sp_a_num` en una lista o lo puedo hacer sin tener que hacer un `.split()`?

```
  def eliminar_stopwords(texto_m_sp_a_num, stop_words):
    """La función eliminar_stopwords recibe el resultado de texto_m_sp_a_num y el fichero stopwords, elimina las stopwords del texto y retorna un texto sin stopwords""" 
    texto_final = re.sub(stop_words, "", texto_m_sp_a_num)
    return texto final

print(eliminar_stopwords(texto_m_sp_a_num, stop_words))
```

Comment: ¿Qué es `stop_words`? ¿Una lista? ¿Una expresión regular? Falta ese detalle.

Comment: "stop_words" es una lista que contiene las palabras que quiero eliminar del texto

Comment: ¿Como reemplazarias "stop1" en la siguiente frase: "stop1: pal stop1pre prestop1  __ stop1 ___  otra enstop1medio stop1."? Ojo: Los "_" representan espacios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, puedes usar la librería `NLTK`, `re`, etc.

Yo te dejo aquí un ejemplo sin librerías, con puro Python:

```
stopwords = ["el", "para", "con", "contra", "de"]
texto = "el perro de ana se encontro con el de maria"

def eliminar_stopwords(texto, stopwords):
    return ' '.join([word for word in texto.split(' ') if word not in stopwords])


print(eliminar_stopwords(texto, stopwords))
```

**Salida:**

```
'perro ana se encontro maria'
```

### Explicación

Te dejo explicado en orden lo que va ocurriendo

1. `split(' ')`: nos divide un string por el caracter que le indiquemos y nos devuelve una lista, en este caso le ponemos un espacio, para indicarle que divida el string por palabras
2. Iteramos por cada palabra de la lista previamente creada con `split(' ')`, con el condicional `if` le indicamos que solo se quede con las palabras que no se encuentren en *"stopwords"*
3. ' '.join(): Una vez la iteración a acabado nos queda una lista, con las palabras que queremos, usamos `' '.join()` para indicarle que nos una todas las palabras de esa lista con espacios. Por lo que tenemos nuestro `string` inicial con las palabras que queremos.

Comment: Muchas gracias! otro problema es que no consigo eliminar las "stopwords" que comienzan los párrafos.  ¿Sabes cómo puedo eliminar esas tambien?

Comment: splitear por salto de línea, comas o puntos suele ser una buena medida extra ( Si en el texto de entrada:no se respeta el espacio entre comas;entre puntos y otros separadores.Es común encontrarse con esos casos. ) eso o normalizar primero el texto.